# How to join two panda series without duplicating keys

Tags: pandas

Series a:

```
one   1
two   1
three 1
```

Series b:

```
two   2
three 2
four  2
```

How can I merge them to get the following result:

```
one    1
two    1
three  1
four   2
```

Any keys that are duplicated, use the value in series a for that key.

I tried this:

pd.merge(a.reset_index(), b.reset_index(), how='outer')

but get:

```
one    1   nan
two    1   2
three  1   2
four   nan 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) method:

```
In [86]: s1 = pd.Series(1, index=[1,2,3])

In [87]: s2 = pd.Series(2, index=[2,3,4])

In [88]: s1.combine_first(s2)
Out[88]: 
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves this simple problem.  I had been using combine_first in more complicated example and was getting some nans.  Will investigate further.